# Подскажите пожалуйста. У меня некорректно работает метод .find() для string

Tags: c++

Пользователь вводит строку sentence. Программа ищет самое длинное слово max. Мне нужно найти индекс первого символа этого слова max. Я воспользовалась sentence.find(max) , но в терминале выводится 0.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
int main () {
std::cout << "Введите предложение: ";
std::string sentence, max;
std::getline(std::cin, sentence);
///// максимальный элемент
std::stringstream ss(sentence);
while (ss >> sentence) {
if (sentence.size()> max.size()) {
    max=sentence;
}
}
std::cout << max << std::endl;
int len = max.length();
//////////// индекс первого символа 
size_t i;
i= sentence.find(max);
std::cout << i;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так ты исходное значение введенной переменной sentence затираешь, используй в цикле другую переменную.

Comment: я поменяла, вывелось это: 18446744073709551615

Comment: плохо поменяли.

Comment: 18446744073709551615 это -1 = std::string::npos - строка не найдена.

Comment: я просто не поняла какую другую переменную использовать: заменить sentence или ss ?

Comment: другую переменную `word`

Comment: извините, но я не понимаю какую переменную на что поменять

Comment: `while (ss >> word) {
   if (word.size() > max.size()) {
     max = word;
  }
}`

Comment: спасибо вам огромное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (ss >> word) {
  if (word.size() > max.size()) {
    max = word;   
  }
}
```